# Subscription in subscription to load data from service into component (Angular)

Tags: angular

I want to load data from two methods from service into a component. This code doesn't work - I don't get the company name, I understand that:

```
private userData;
private companyName;

ngOnInit() {

    this.dataService.getUser(this.idUser).subscribe((user) => {
        this.userData = user[`data`][0];
    });

    this.dataService.getCompany(this.userData.id_company).subscribe((company) => {
        this.companyName = company[`data`][0].name;
    });

}
```

Then I do subscription in subscription:

```
private userData;
private companyName;

ngOnInit() {

    this.dataService.getUser(this.idUser).subscribe((user) => {

        this.userData = user[`data`][0];

        this.dataService.getCompany(this.userData.id_company).subscribe((company) => {
            this.companyName = company[`data`][0].name;
        });

    });

}
```

Is this good practice to do that? Is there any alternative way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) operator

```js
    this.dataService.getUser(this.idUser).pipe(
       map(resp => resp.data[0]),
       switchMap(user => this.dataService.getCompany(user.id_company).pipe(
          map(resp => [user, resp.data[0]])
       ))
    ).subscribe(([user, company]) => {
       this.user = user;
       this.companyName = company.name;
    });
```